# Override a column of an entity in the select clause with hql without enumarate all columns

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql

I would like override a column of an entity in the select clause with hql (not sql!) without enumarate all columns.
I won't put here my entities, because they are complicated. Instead, I simplify the question by a simple example.

Consider I have a CarEntity:

```
public CarEntity{
    private Long id;
    private Integer color;
    private Long Date;
    //...

    //getters and setters
}
```

To get all cars, I do the following hql request :

```
String query = "select c from CarEntity c";
```

Now, I would like replacing the Date value by 0 in the select clause in the hql. **How can I do this?**

I know 3 possibilities that do not interest me because my entities have a lot of columns :

1) java (not a good solution):

```
String hql = "select c from CarEntity c";
List<CarEntity> list = session.createQuery(hql).list();
session.close();
for (CarEntity car: list)
    car.setDate(0);
```

2) sql :

```
String sql = "select id, 0 as date from car";
List<CarEntity> list = session.createSQLQuery(sql)
    .addScalar("id",LongType.INSTANCE)
    .addScalar("date",LongType.INSTANCE)
    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(CarEntity.class))
    .list();
```

3) hql (use of new CarEntity in select clause) :

```
String hql = "select new CarEntity(c.id,0) from CarEntity c";
```

Of course, in the latest case, I have to add a new suitable constructor in the CarEntity.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Entities are supposed to represent what there actually is in the database. If you want an object to represent something else, use another object. The first solution, for example, will persist 0 in the date column of every row retrieved by the query.

Comment: ok, thx for your answer. Good point for the persistance in the first example. But as I said here I simplified the problem. Consider in the first example, I detach the object by closing the session :-). I will edit and correct this in the main post right away. So you advise to use an other object, mais dans mon problème qui n'est pas tout à fait exposé ici, cela ne me convient pas tout à fait :-) Je vais attendre , réfléchir et voir un peu... :-) EN tout cas merci.

Comment: What is the actual use case?  As JB notes above, entities are supposed to model DB data.  If you need to override a value in the DB for some reason, address that use case and put the business logic where it belongs - in the service/business tier, not the data access tier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look at the problem in a different way if you have a service layer that talks to DAO layer and returns a VO/DTO but preferably not entity itself. In this case you can have transient fields in the entity or build the logic in service layer. But again it depends on the existing design of your application.